# nodejs connect to mysql DB "INSERT command denied to user"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to connect mysql DB and insert some values into the table. But I get the result: "INSERT command denied to user '' @'localhost' for table 'paramenttable'".

[DB connection page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHRSP.png)

(to call the two function in route.js like this:)

```
mysqlinsertp.conn();

mysqlinsertp.insert(array_1);
```

[the error page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dtmZ.png)

Comment: the user gjj has permission to insert in the table?

Comment: @LucasCosta yes, the user gjj has the permission to insert to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config for mysql could not be found in that variable. The module exports of `settings.js` provide a `mysql` item. You should use that instead of the root.

Your client initialization should be following:

`var client = mysql.createConnection(settings.mysql);`

instead of `mysql.createConnection(settings);`